# Kotlin annotation processor gives compile time error while using Room with Android Studio 3.0 beta7

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0, kapt

I'm compiling Android project using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7, using Kotlin 1.4-2 and [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) 1.0.0-beta1.

This is part of my Gradle file where I'm adding Room dependancies:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-beta1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-beta1"
```

While compiling I'm getting following error:

> Warning:warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation
>   processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than
>   -source '1.8'

After adding stacktrace/debug flags to compile options this is the error I'm getting:

> Error:org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while
>   annotation processing
>
> 10:08:03.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   10:08:03.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   10:08:03.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   10:08:03.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
>   10:08:03.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   10:08:03.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Internal compiler error. See log for more details
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>   10:08:03.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Internal compiler error. See log for more details
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:9)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptTask.compile(KaptTask.kt:71)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:731)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>   10:08:03.729 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>   10:08:03.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
>   10:08:03.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>   10:08:03.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 27 more
>   10:08:03.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   10:08:03.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
>   10:08:03.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   10:08:03.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
>   10:08:03.730 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 8s

Clean/rebuild doesn't help. What might be causing this error? The temporary solution seems to be replacing "kapt" with standard "annotationProcessor", rebuild and then building again with "kapt". But after further changes in the project the error keeps popping again.

[EDIT]

My Gradle file (app module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mydomain.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    // Anko Commons
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

    // Timber logging
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber_version"

    // Architecture components - Lifecycle
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$arch_version"
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$arch_version"

    // Architecture components - Room ORM
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$arch_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$arch_version"

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"

    // Picasso
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$picasso_version"
}
```

Gradle (project module):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'
    ext.timber_version = '4.5.1'
    ext.retrofit_version = '2.3.0'
    ext.picasso_version = '2.5.2'
    ext.constraint_layout_version = '1.0.2'
    ext.support_library_version = '26.1.0'
    ext.arch_version = '1.0.0-beta1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta7'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Ignore warning it is irrelevant. Open `View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal` and type `gradlew build`. Navigate to see the cause of the exception. It is most like you configure Room  wrong. As Room do compile time checking, therefore you cannot build it.

Comment: Post your whole app module `build.gradle` file and `gradle` build log

Comment: @Joshua I don't think so since a)I don't have any Room code there yet b)had the same error with "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-beta1" and c)It disappeared  when I did what I mentioned at the end of my post.

Comment: @VictorNidens - edited.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using kapt plugin and room too, and had a similar error. In my case, I solved it by moving the this line     `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`from the `app build.gradle` to the `top build.gradle`, outside the `buildscript{}` block, then the error is gone.
[I found it here](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt)

Comment: This seems to solve the problem, I'll test it for 1-2 days before I accept your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dependency version `1.0.0-beta1` use `1.0.0-beta2` and try compiling.

Comment: Will check that, so far didn't have this issue again anymore but I'm still on beta1.

Comment: The docs are stating that the dependency version has been updated to `beta2` for architecture components.

Comment: Yep, seen that, thanks (I will stay on beta1 to make sure this issue is happening due to that, will update later :))

Comment: Still happened while using 1.0.0-beta2.

Comment: I'll surely look into it and try to find the best possible solution.